# How to find the associated Legendre functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, legendre-functions

Reading the Courant-Hilbert *Methods of Mathematical Physics*  (p.326) we encounter:

"...If we differentiate equation
$$
\left[(1-x^2)u')\right]'+\lambda u=0
$$
with respect to $x$, we obtain a differential equation for the function $u'(x)$. ....It follows that a solution which is regular at both end points of the interval exist only for $\lambda=n(n+1)$and is given in this case by $P'_n(x)$. "

Here $P'_n(x)$ is the derivative of the Legendre polynomial, solution of the preceding equation.

I understand that this way.
The equation is $(L+\lambda)u=0$ with $L$ the linear operator $L u=\left[(1-x^2)u' \right]'$. If $D$ is the linear operator $Du=u'$ than we have $D(Lu+\lambda u)=DL u+\lambda Du=0$.

But I don't see how to prove the statement from here because, obviously $DL\ne LD$.

Explicitly we have
$$
DL u=\left[ (1-x^2)u''-2xu' \right]'
$$
so the equation becomes:
$$
\left[ (1-x^2)u'' \right]'-2u'-2xu''+\lambda u'=0
$$
or, with $u'=v$
$$
\left[ (1-x^2)v' \right]'-2xv'+(\lambda-2) v=0
$$
and also here i don't see how to proceed.

Comment: I think that the authors are referring to solving the equation reached when differentiating the Legendre equation: $L v = -\lambda v$ where $L = [ (1-x^2) \cdot ]^{''}$ and $v = u^{'} $. I don't have a copy of that book - is there any hint just before this where a similar equation is studied?